# How to handle UIApplication handleOpenURL with many return?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

i'm getting problem with the function in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

A lot of libraries must put some return code in this function for their configurations. Like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
//facebook
 //attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];

//library
BOOL urlHasBeenHandledByDispatcher = [[GRKConnectorsDispatcher sharedInstance] dispatchURLToConnectingServiceConnector:url];
if ( urlHasBeenHandledByDispatcher  ) return YES;
return NO;

//facebookSession
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

How can I config in this situation to make all the library working?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code and return value only once. Try following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
//facebook
 //attempt to extract a token from the url
    BOOL result = NO;
    result |= [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];

//library
result |= [[GRKConnectorsDispatcher sharedInstance] dispatchURLToConnectingServiceConnector:url];
//facebookSession
result |= [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
return result;
}
```

This method will return `YES` if at least one library returns `YES`, and `NO` otherwise.